# If a sequence of random variables $X_n \sim \mathrm{Poisson}(1/n) $, Show that $X_n \to 0$ and $Y_n = n X_n  \to 0$?

Tags: probability

I have this problem:

Let $X_n \sim \mathrm{Poisson}(1/n)$. Show that $X_n \to 0$ and $Y_n = n X_n \to 0$?

I already proved the first statement, but every time I try to show the second one I get a divergent result. Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: What sort of convergence are you interested in? The $\to$ can mean at least a few different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy to show that $Y_n \to 0$ in probability (hence also in distribution). Indeed, for any fixed $\varepsilon > 0$ and as $n \to \infty$,
$$
{\rm P}(nX_n  > \varepsilon ) = {\rm P}(X_n  > \varepsilon /n) = 1 - {\rm P}(X_n  \le \varepsilon /n) = 1 - {\rm P}(X_n  = 0) = 1 - e^{-1/n} \to 0.
$$

Exercise: Prove this using characteristic functions.

EDIT: Actually, for any sequence $(a_n)$ it trivially holds that $a_n X_n \to 0$ in probability, since
$$
{\rm P}(a_n X_n  = 0) \ge {\rm P}(X_n  = 0) = e^{ - 1/n}  \to 1.
$$
As a further exercise, let's consider the case where $X_n \sim {\rm N}(0,1/n)$. Then, the characteristic function of $a_n X_n$ is given by
$$
{\rm E}[e^{{\rm i}t(a_n X_n) } ] = {\rm E}[e^{{\rm i}(a_n t)X_n } ] = e^{ - n^{ - 1} a_n^2 t^2 /2}.
$$
Thus we need $a_n^2 /n \to 0$ in order to have that $a_n X_n \to 0$ in distribution, hence also in probability (note that convergence in distribution to a constant $c$ implies convergence in probability to $c$; here $c=0$).

Remark. For the last example, rather than using characteristic functions, just notice that $a_n X_n$ is equal in distribution to $(a_n / \sqrt{n}) Z$, where $Z \sim {\rm N}(0,1)$.

Comment: I was interested in probability, the way I was doing it was  squaring both sides inside the probability and using Markov inequality and then trying to show E(Y_n^2) \rightarrow 0, which is much more difficult than that...

Comment: I was interested in  probability, the way I was doing it was P(|Yn|>epsilon)=P(|Yn|^2>epsilon^2) using Markov inequality and then trying to show E(Yn^2) -> 0, which envolve to show that E(Yn^2) +E(Yn)^2 ->0. But as always simplicity is the way!!

Comment: Indeed, expectations are not useful here: ${\rm E}(nX_n) = n(1/n)=1$, ${\rm Var}(nX_n) = n^2 (1/n) \to \infty$.

Comment: Yes I found that, thanks